# Flickering of recyclerview when fetching imagerequests

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley, picasso

I experienced a flickering of the imageviews in my recyclerview when scrolling very fast. All the imagerequests would be downloaded and showed. This would a weird effect on the imageviews.

I'm using Volley library to execute the downloads, together with Picasso to show the images. Yes this is a funny combination, but I needed to customise my headers & have authentication of my requests. Picasso not allowing me this easily.

I have experimented with a lot of possibilities;
 - Pausing the requestQueue when scrolling. Resume downloads when idle. This would result in the same issue, but delayed.
- Use of Volley's imageLoader/NetworkImageView. Imageloader cannot be customized like a volley request.
- Delete all requests when scrolling. Resume when idle. This would result with imageviews not being downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

So as I didn't find any easy solution online, I would like to share mine.
2 lines of code that are now perfectly working with my existing code;

```
MyApplication.mRequestqueue.cancelAll(imgView);
imageRequest.setTag(imgView);
```

Then I add my request
    MyApplication.mRequestqueue.add(imageRequest);

the imgView is a... ImageView

I tried with a String but behind the scenes it is checking for == and not equal, resulting in not finding and cancelling the same requests going on.

Hope this will help someone!